# Does the \setlength have any feature not found in geometry package ؟

Tags: geometry, calc

Do we need to use  `\setlength`  if we use the geometry package? Does the `\setlength` have any feature not found in  geometry package?

Comment: This depends what for. This command can be used in a lot of contexts which are not necessarily about the page layout.

Comment: you question can't have an answer the two things are more or less completely unrelated. `\setlength` is a core latex command that sets a length register to a value. geometry is a package that knows about page sizes like A4 and page layout concepts like two-column, and allows lengths to be specified that don't correspond to length registers, such as margins